Concatenating values of Json only when inputted via Jolt
I have the following inputted Json:
{
  "extraFields": {
    "language": "french",
    "status": {
      "comment": "hey"
    }
  }
}

Using Jolt, I want to achieve the following output:
{
  "extraFields": "{\"language\": \"french\", \"status\": {\"comment\": \"hey\"}}"
}

Note the backslashes.
I managed to do that with the following Jolt formula:
[
  {
    "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
    "spec": {
      "extraFields": "=concat('{', '\"language\": ', '\"', @(0,language), '\" ,', '\"status\": ', '{', '\"comment\": ', '\"', @(1,extraFields.status.comment), '\"', '}', '}')"
    }
  }
]


Problem is, fields of extraFields are optional meaning, some of them might not be inputted.
For example, status can be omitted or language or both.
It results, empty values of non-inputted keys.
Is it possible to concatenate only inputted keys?

You can pad the related characters by using a shift, then stringify the attribute by a modify transformation through use of toString function such as
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "language": {
          "*": "&2.\"&1\".\"&\""
        },
        "status": {
          "*": {
            "*": "&3.\"&2\".\"&1\".\"&\""
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "*language*": {
          "*": {
            "$": "&3.&2"
          }
        },
        "*status*": {
          "*": {
            "*": {
              "$": "&4.&3.&2"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
    "spec": {
      "*": "=toString"
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
    "spec": {
      "temp1": "=toString(@(1,extraFields))",
      "temp2": "=split('=',@(1,temp1))",
      "extraFields": "=join(':',@(1,temp2))"
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "remove",
    "spec": {
      "temp*": ""
    }
  }
]


Great answer!, though running with the Jolt Demo I get:
{
"extraFields" : "{"language"="french", "status"={"comment"="hey"}}"
}
i.e. '=' instead of ':'
I attempted to fix it, but I didn't quite succeed. could you give a try?

Oh my bad, haven't noticed before, just fixed the issue now @DoubleS

Incredible! Just one last question, if you don't mind helping out. "extraFields" resides as a key within a larger Json structure (for instance, there's another key like "name" at the same level). My aim is to keep all the other fields intact and solely tweak "extraFields". could you assist please?

Need to add the similar portion like the others for name as well @DoubleS Since we cannot define a generic rule as having different levels

I understand, but doing it with the temp step is quite cumbersome. Could you handle it? Attatch it in other response. I believe it will be helpful for the general case as well.

For the general case where extraFields resides as a key within a larger Json structure for instance, there's another key name at the same level i.e.
{
  "name": "Michael Jackson",
  "number": 3,
  "extraFields": {
    "language": "french",
    "status": {
      "comment": "hey"
    }
  }
}

Aiming to keep all other fields intact and solely tweak extraFields.
The corresponding Jolt would be:
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": "&",
      "extraFields": {
        "language": {
          "*": "&2.\"&1\".\"&\""
        },
        "status": {
          "*": {
            "*": "&3.\"&2\".\"&1\".\"&\""
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": "&",
      "extraFields": {
        "*language*": {
          "*": {
            "$": "&3.&2"
          }
        },
        "*status*": {
          "*": {
            "*": {
              "$": "&4.&3.&2"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
    "spec": {
      "extraFields": {
        "*": "=toString"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
    "spec": {
      "temp1": "=toString(@(1,extraFields))",
      "temp2": "=split('=',@(1,temp1))",
      "extraFields": "=join(':',@(1,temp2))"
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "remove",
    "spec": {
      "temp*": ""
    }
  }
]

Credit to Barbaros Özhan
